# Visual Studio Emulator for Android not starting. Stuck at preparing

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

I'm am unable to start the Android emulator.

I have found a number of similar questions relating to this and have tried several resolutions without success.

But I don't get exit code 3 error. The VS emulator for Android just hangs at the preparation stage forever.

I have disabled all my networks so it is not sharing.

I have repaired the VS Emulator.

There are no switches in the Hyper-V manager to delete.

I have run xdecleanup.exe.

I'm a member of the Hyper-V Admin group.

The only error in the log file is:

3> 16-May-16 11:00:38 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: CouldntCreateInternalSwitch (16)

But that only appears after I kill xde.exe.

I've run out of options to get this product working.

Appreciate any tips or advice.

One question I have is; what virtualisation technology is required to provide the VS android emulator?  Hyper-V or Virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it going!

1. Kill all running xde.exe (processes)
2. Repair Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android
3. Remove all Hyper-V switches
4. Run xdecleanup.exe
5. Completely disable all network adapters.

(The first four steps have been covered in more detail in other articles)

And now it works.

The 5th step is related to the network sharing issue that is described in other articles.  However since I wasn't sharing anything I was forced to go one step further and disable all networks.

Once the emulator is started I can re-enable my networks and it continues to operate.

But if I stop the emulator I must disable all networks before attempting to restart it.

If I make the mistake of attempting to run the emulator with the network enabled I must re-perform all the above steps.